# Lua String Append

Tags: function, lua, metatable

So I created a function that all strings can use and it's called append.

```
local strmt = getmetatable("")
function strmt.__index.append(self, str)
  self = self..str
  return self
end
```

The function is then used like this:

```
self = self:append("stuff")
```

Is there a way to create a function that does just this:

```
local stuff = "hi "
stuff:append("bye")
print(stuff)
```

And produces

```
hi bye
```

Comment: BTW, your first function I don't think you need to mess you meta-tables.  This should be enough: function string:append(s) return self .. s end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Strings in Lua are immutable; if you set `stuff` to `"hi "`, it will equal `"hi "` until you set it to something else. `"hi "` will never become `"hi bye"`, any more than `3` will become `4`.